# Best way to store the bigger out of 2 numbers

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to make my python program as optimised as possible, and there is this portion I am unsure about. I need to store the largest value obtained so far, and I have 2 candidate codes to do so. Which one is the most time-optimised? Or is there a faster way to do so?

Code 1:

```
if value > biggest_value:
    biggest_value = value
```

Code 2:

```
biggest_value = max(biggest_value, value)
```

Context:

```
def check_palindrome(num):
    num = str(num)
    if len(num) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if num[0] == num[-1]:
            return check_palindrome(num[1:-1])
        else:
            return False


def main():
    biggest_product = 0
    for a in range(100, 1000):
        for b in range(100, 1000):
            product = a * b
            if check_palindrome(product):
                # store the biggest_product here
    return biggest_product

main()
```

Comment: You can simply measure which one is faster in your case, then you will know.

Comment: Doing this as optimised as possible may well mean not to do this at all (e.g. having values pre-sorted), doing it in bulk (e.g. via numpy) or doing it with an extension (e.g. numba or Cython). Can you provide *any* context in which this very minor operation needs to be optimised?

Comment: If you think this line is going to make a significant difference to the running time of your program, you can try it both ways see if it has any effect (spoilers: it will not).

Comment: Optimising the comparison seems like a red herring here. Function calls are very expensive in Python, meaning the recursive palindrome check is going to thwart whatever is done with the result. The way of constructing products also is very inefficient, checking every value *at least* twice but most values many more.

Comment: Even for the worst-case of a large number whose first check fails, ``return num == num[::-1]`` is 10% faster than your recursive check (this difference is roughly as much as the biggest value check takes). For an actual palindrome that needs checking all digits, your version is five times slower. Note that you don't need to check if the new number is larger than the last if numbers are generated in ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

Code 2 is the better option because in Code 1 you have to compare the numbers with 2 commands ( < = ) and in Code 2 you only have one command.

Good Luck with your Programm and have fun!

Jonas

Comment: What do you mean by "compare with 3 commands"? There is only one comparison performed, namely ``>``.

Comment: If you want to compare them you also have to check if they are the same value.

Comment: The first code does not check whether they are the same value. There doesn't seem to be a need to make that comparison, either - if they are the same, then ``biggest_value`` already equals ``value`` by definition and nothing needs to be done.

Comment: Oh okay now i understand your problem. Thanks for correcting me ;) If you want to figure out which is faster you can run a speed test with both codes.